# How to not repeat same variable name when reading from a .txt file

Tags: c++

I have this .txt file

```
Anna 70 79 72 78 71 73 68 74 75 70
Jason 78 89 96 91 94 95 92 88 95 92
kim 83 81 93 85 84 79 78 90 88 79
Maria 93 100 86 99 98 97 96 95 94 92
Daniel 72 60 82 64 65 63 62 61 67 64
```

I have to store the name and the average of the 10 numbers in a vector of struct that has two variables, string name & int average.

I was doing this way:

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
    int score;
};

int main() {

string defaultPath = "lab2.txt";
ifstream inFile(defaultPath);

while (inFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Fail while opening the file.\n";
    cout << "Please enter a different .txt name/directory: ";
    getline(cin, defaultPath);
}

string name;
int score = 0, totalScore = 0, averageScore = 0;

vector<Student> studentData;

while (inFile >> name >> score >> score >> score >> score >> score >> score
              >> score >> score >> score >> score)
{
    totalScore += score;
    averageScore = totalScore / 10;

    studentData.push_back({name, score});
}

}
```

The thing is that what stores in the vector from score is the last num of score from the .txt file (70,92,79...) because it is reassigning score again and again before going to the code to calculate the average.

I tried creating another loops inside the while loop but w/o success.. The only way that I think it would work is to assign a variable name to each number (ex. score1, score2, score3... score10) but I'm sure there is other way more efficient to do it! Not sure how..

Comment: slightly offtopic: you'll never leave the `while (inFile.fail())` loop

Comment: *"score1, score2, score3... score10"*, that is generally sign that `vector`/`array` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from making 10 `score` variables with different names,
you can get the scores in the loop:

```
while (inFile >> name)
{
    while (infile >> score)
    {
        totalScore += score;
    }
    averageScore = totalScore / 10;

    studentData.push_back({name, score});
}
```

(I presume you realise you aren't storing the average that you've calculated?)

Comment: I think you meant to say `studentData.push_back({name,averageScore});` to actually store the average.

Comment: Possibly. I did note that average wasn't being used, by way of an exercise for the reader.